# Is there a way I can recieve code to my Email instead entering it from Google Authenticator App?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

Can we email Google authentication code instead of entering it through Google Authentication? Many customers do not want to install the app for this and prefer email through the mobile app. I lost my mind but found no solution.

Comment: MFA on a mobile app is actually pretty common nowadays

Comment: Yes you can send an email . for reference see this and instead of sms use email : https://damienbod.com/2017/07/14/implementing-two-factor-authentication-with-identityserver4-and-twilio/